# Python telegram bot, indentation errors while importing

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm working on a telegram bot to return stock price info. Normally I can import telegram module easily. But whenever I run this code, the errors would come up as below:

> Exception has occurred: IndentationError
> expected an indented block after function definition on line 13 (telegram.py, line 16)
> File "D:\Telegram Bot\tele_stock_bot2.py", line 4, in 
> import telegram.ext
> IndentationError: expected an indented block after function definition on line 13 (telegram.py, line 16)

Below is my code:

```
from vnstock import *
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
import telegram.ext
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, Updater, MessageHandler, Filters

print('Bot started ...')

# Define a function to handle the /start command
def start_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(text="Hi! Try /sum [ticker]]")



# Define a function to get the last trading day
def last_trading_day():
    today = datetime.datetime.now() # Get today's date AND TIME
    
    # If today is weekday and the current time is before 9:15 AM, get yesterday's date
    if today.weekday() < 5 and today.time() < datetime.time(hour=9, minute=15):
        last_trading_day = today - timedelta(days=1)   

    elif today.weekday() == 6: # If today is Sunday, get last Friday
        last_trading_day = today - timedelta(days=2)   
    
    elif today.weekday() == 5: # If today is Saturday, get last Friday
        last_trading_day = today - timedelta(days=1)
    # Otherwise, get today
    else:
        last_trading_day = today - timedelta(days=0)

    return last_trading_day

# Define a function to handle the /sum command
def sum_command(update, context):
    ticker = context.args[0].upper()     # Get the stock ticker from user input
    try:
        #today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        
        T_0 = last_trading_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
        #define last_trading_day()[1] aka T-1
        if last_trading_day.weekday() == 0: # If last trading day is Monday, get last Friday
            start_date = last_trading_day - timedelta(days = 4)
        else: # Otherwise, get last trading day minus one
            start_date = last_trading_day - timedelta(days = 2)

        T_minus_2 = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


        # Get the stock data:
        stock_data = stock_historical_data(ticker, T_minus_2, T_0)
       
        price = stock_data.iloc[0, 3]
        vol = stock_data.iloc[0, 4]
        high = stock_data.iloc[0, 1]
        low = stock_data.iloc[0, 2]
        close_prev = stock_data.iloc[1,3]
        price_change = price - close_prev
        perc_change = (price_change / close_prev)*100
        price_change = round(price_change,0)
        perc_change = round(perc_change,2)
        if price_change >0:
            price_change_str = f'+{price_change:.0f}'
            perc_change_str = f'+{perc_change:.2f}'
        else:
            price_change_str = f'{price_change:.0f}'
            perc_change_str = f'{perc_change:.2f}'

        message = f"Latest information for {ticker}:\n"
        message += f"Price: {price}\n"
        message += f"Volume: {vol}\n"
        message += f"High: {high}\n"
        message += f"Low: {low}\n"
        message += f"Change: {price_change_str} , {perc_change_str}%\n"
        

        update.message.reply_text(text=message)
    
    except:
        update.message.reply_text(text=f"Error retrieving information for {ticker}. Please check the ticker and try again.")


def handle_message(update, context):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower
    response = 'I\'m not here to chitchat. Use /sum [ticker] command plz'
    update.message.reply_text(response)

# Set up the Telegram bot
def main():
    API_KEY = '......'
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=API_KEY)
    updater = Updater(API_KEY, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Add handlers for the /overview and /start commands
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('sum', sum_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))

    # Start the bot
    updater.start_polling(5)
    updater.idle()

main()
```

That line is not indented, therefore I don't understand how to fix this error. Would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your indentation is OK.

Comment: Thank you. But whenever I try to run, the IndentationError would show up and pointing towards that 'import telegram' line. I really don't understand why. I'm pretty new to this btw.

Comment: Comment out this `import #telegram.ext`

Comment: if I comment that line out, the error will show up at the next line `from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, Updater, MessageHandler, Filters` @toyotaSupra

Comment: I guess you installed `python-telegram`, in which case there should be a third-party library `telegram` package that contains `ext.py`. But `import telegram.ext` can also try to import a `telegram` *module* in a `telegram.py` file (which would then fail because it's not a package, so it can't find the `ext.py`). It seems that your project contains its own `telegram.py` which is found instead of the third-party library. But even before there can be an import error, you got a syntax error because there is a syntax error in the code of  your `telegram.py` file.

Comment: I added a duplicate link to explain the situation with `telegram.py`, and then another one to explain how to fix the syntax error in that file (you will *also* need to rename it).

Answer (score -1):

Try comment out the `# import telegram.ext`.

When importing `from telegram.ext`, use "`filters`", not "`Filters`", because the file `__init__.py` does not contain an extension with that name.

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, Updater, MessageHandler, filters
```

---

Also try changing the import completely.

1. Change your import to:

```
# You should only use "from vnstock import *" if the documentation
# of the "vnstock" module declare it to be safe and lists the
# actually imported symbols.
import vnstock
# Comment out or delete
# import datetime
# Add to "import from datetime" - "datetime, time"
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime, time
```

2. Change the lines:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
# and
if today.weekday() < 5 and today.time() < datetime.time(hour=9, minute=15):
```

to

```
today = datetime.now()
# and
if today.weekday() < 5 and today.time() < time(hour=9, minute=15):
```

Comment: Thank you! But the error is still there no matter how I edit. Only if I completely remove the import of telegram bot then it would not show up (but then the code wouldn't work). Also, if I look into the error, it seems to have a problem with the module itself since it keeps pointing towards lines 13 & 16 of telegram.py file. Is it the issue?

Comment: `Exception has occurred: IndentationError
expected an indented block after function definition on line 13 (telegram.py, line 16)
  File "D:\Telegram Bot\eztock_bot_3.py", line 5, in <module>
    import telegram
IndentationError: expected an indented block after function definition on line 13 (telegram.py, line 16)`

Comment: The problem is that the OP's code contains a `telegram.py` file that is shadowing a third-party library. You can tell because the code tries to import `telegram.ext`, so `telegram` should be a package, but the error message complains about the content of `telegram.py`. (If `telegram` were properly a package, then `telegram` would be the name of a folder somewhere, and if any code were executed to load the package, it would be in an `__init__.py` in that folder.)